# Powershell : PSDebug in Transcript yet NOT displayed terminal?

Tags: powershell

When running my script, I want the output of "Set-PSDebug -Trace2" to appear in my Transcript, yet the terminal itself to remain as if PSDebug was off.
Is this possible?

C:/test/test.ps1 contains :

```
Set-PSDebug -Trace 2
Start-Transcript C:\test\transcript.txt -append
$Test = "This is just a test"
"$Test"
```

i run it like so :

```
& 'C:/test/test.ps1'
```

when run the terminal displays this :

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> & 'C:/test/test.ps1'
Transcript started, output file is C:\test\transcript.txt
DEBUG:    4+ $Test = <<<<  "This is just a test"
DEBUG:     ! SET $Test = 'This is just a test'.
DEBUG:    5+ "$Test" <<<<
This is just a test
DEBUG:    2+         $foundSuggestion = <<<<  $false
DEBUG:     ! SET $foundSuggestion = 'False'.
DEBUG:    4+         if <<<< ($lastError -and
DEBUG:   15+         $foundSuggestion <<<<
PS C:\Users\Admin>
```

And "transcript.txt" displays the same.

So again, my question is whether it is possible for the terminal to display no DEBUG: info while the transcript does, and if so, how to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thats interesting. For me, the same script shows debug info in the console, but does not show any debug info in the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of writing your own PowerShell host to handle screen output, there is no way to prevent Trace debug output to the screen while at the same time have it logged via `Start-Transcript`.  AFAICT the trace debug output doesn't even honor the `$DebugPreference` setting.